# How to create a custom admin panel for many models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to create a custom ModelAdmin, but for a mix of models, not just one.

I have two example models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    # ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    # ...
```

Now I want to be able to have a ModelAdmin with fields:

```
author
number_of_comments
number_of_articles
```

How can I achieve it?

I created a new ModelAdmin with overridden `queryset` method, but I was not able to register it, because `Article` and `Comment` are already registered.

Comment: Could you paste your codes of the 'new ModelAdmin'

Comment: @ZZY I thought about something like this http://pastebin.com/2LLvM7Br but now I think it won't work that way.